# How to mount swap partition on /mnt in ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, swap

one of our ec2 instances is running out of RAM and there no way to upgrade the RAM without changing the instance type... So I need to upgrade the size of the swap for the moment.

My question is: is it possible to mount a swap partition on the "ephemeral storage" /mnt ?

Thank you!

Comment: no there is no way you can mount a `swap` partition, because it not a filesystem. But you probably meant 'swap on another partition' (which **needs** to be not mounted)

Comment: thank you sehe, that's what i meant. I gonna try with a swap file on that partition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, there is pretty simple script we use. Can be found over web.

```
if [ $SWAP_SIZE_MEGABYTES -eq 0 ];then
  echo No swap size given, skipping.
else  
  if [ -e /swapfile ];then    
     echo /swapfile already exists.  Skipping.  
  else    
     echo Creating /swapfile of $SWAP_SIZE_MEGABYTES Megabytes    
     dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=$(($SWAP_SIZE_MEGABYTES*1024))    
     mkswap /swapfile    
     swapon /swapfile    
     echo Swap Status:    
     swapon -s  
  fi
fi
```